# Phoenix endpoint server for tests won't start

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on ex_admin and ran into a problem starting the Phoenix server. I am working on setting up integration tests with Hound. ex_admin has a Phoenix endpoint in the test/support framework. When I set the config for the endpoint server to true I get an error:

```
    ** (EXIT from #PID<0.70.0>) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server
   ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: {:ranch_listener_sup, TestExAdmin.Endpoint.HTTP}
       ** (EXIT) exited in: :gen_server.call(:ranch_server, {:set_new_listener_opts, TestExAdmin.Endpoint.HTTP, 16384, [env: [dispatch: [{:_, [], [{:_, [], Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {TestExAdmin.Endpoint, []}}]}]]]})
           ** (EXIT) no process
```

You can see the code here: https://github.com/gwincr11/ex_admin

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that `Phoenix.Endpoint.Server` failed to start a `:ranch_listener_sup` because `:ranch_server` was not running. This is because you are not starting `cowboy` (ranch is a dependency of cowboy and will automatically be started if you start `cowboy`) in your test env.

To fix this, you can either add the following to the top of `test/test_helper.exs`:

```
Application.ensure_all_started(:cowboy)
```

Or add it as a dependency in `:test` env in `mix.exs`:

```
defp applications(:test) do
  [:plug, :cowboy | applications(:prod)]
end
```

After making either one of these changes, I no longer get that error in your codebase (but I get 7 test failures which you probably added and not had the chance to fix).

Comment: That was it, thanks so much. It would be nice if the error actually told you what application was not started. I kind of assumed starting cowboy would have been handled by Phoenix. I got all my failed test passing, I was trying all kinds of configs to get the server started which affected my tests.

Comment: Do you know, is there a way I can actually start the Phoenix endpoint and server in the test support folder so I can access on my local machine?